# Typer Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dhtmlx-scheduler

I’m creating a node.js app and implementing the scheduler app. I’m following this walkthrough: https://dhtmlx.com/blog/using-dhtmlxscheduler-with-node-js/

When I navigate to the /data page, it says cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I went to the github page and downloaded app.js word for word.

Here is app.js portion throwing error:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
db.event.find().toArray(function(err, data){
    //set id property for all records
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        data[i].id = data[i]._id;

    //output response
    res.send(data);
});
});
```

Comment: `data` is undefined, have you checked if there was an error? What do you get when you put `console.log(err)` before the for-loop?

Comment: `Error occured with no callback to handle it while calling SkinCollection.insert Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed`

Comment: here is the git repo I cloned, still getting the error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.  [link](https://github.com/DHTMLX/node-scheduler-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [example](https://github.com/DHTMLX/node-scheduler-demo)  works fine. I guess, in your case,  `mongoskin` fails to connect to mongodb for some reasons. If I change some parts in this path `mongodb://localhost/testdb` (for testing purpose, put some random string) , `mongodb` will complain about problem with `url`, and I'll get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` from node js, because there will be no data fetched from database.

Comment: I just got this to work. I’m using MongoDB atlas and for some reason switching my connection string from the Short SRV string to standard made it work